# Efficient way to find out if two sorted lists contain same element Java.

Tags: java, performance, new-operator

I have a tight loop that searches coprimes. A list `primeFactors`. Its n-th element contains a sorted list of prime decomposition of n. I am checking if `c` and `d` are coprimes using `checkIfPrimes`

```
boolean checkIfPrimes(int c, int d, List<List<Integer>> primeFactors) {
    List<Integer>  common = new ArrayList<>(primeFactors.get(d)); //slow
    common.retainAll(primeFactors.get(c));        
    return (common.isEmpty());
}
```

`primeFactors.get(d).retainAll(primeFactors.get(c))` looks promising, but it will alter my reusable `primeFactors` object.

Creating a new object is relatively slow. Is there a way to speed up this step? Can I somehow utilize the fact that lists are sorted? Should I use arrays instead?

Comment: What version of Java?  If 8+, you have quite a few performance-related alternatives

Comment: @JoeG Yes, it is Java8.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [`Collections.disjoint()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection)).

Comment: Or is it [`List.containsAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set operations should be faster than array operations.
Just for kicks, consider trying this and compare the performance against the stream performance:

```
final Set<Integer> commonSet;
final Set<Integer> cSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
final Set<Integer> dSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

cSet.addAll(primeFactors.get(c));
dSet.addAll(primeFactors.get(d));

commonSet = dSet.retainAll(cSet);

return (commonSet.isEmpty());
```

Also,
consider using `List<Set<Integer>> primeFactors`
instead of `List<List<Integer>> primeFactors` since I suspect that you don't
really have a list of prime factors but actually have a set of prime factors.

Comment: If you store list of sets, dont create the new sets, just use those sets.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Collection` with faster lookup - e.g. a `Set` if you only need the prime factors without repetitions, or a `Map` if you also need the count of each factor.

Basically, you want to know whether the intersection of two Sets is empty. [Oracle  Set tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) shows a way to calculate the intersecton (similar to what you already mentioned, using `retainAll` on a copy, but on Sets the operation should be more efficient).

Answer (score 2):

Since your lists are relatively small, and this operation is executed very often, you should avoid creating any new Lists or Sets, because it might lead to a significant GC pressure.

The scan linear algorithm is

```
public static boolean emptyIntersection(List<Integer> sortedA, List<Integer> sortedB) {
    if (sortedA.isEmpty() || sortedB.isEmpty())
        return true;
    int sizeA = sortedA.size(), sizeB = sortedB.size();
    int indexA = 0, indexB = 0;
    int elementA = sortedA.get(indexA), elementB = sortedB.get(indexB);
    while (true) {
        if (elementA == elementB) {
            return false;
        } else if (elementA < elementB) {
            indexA++;
            if (indexA == sizeA)
                return true;
            elementA = sortedA.get(indexA);
        } else {
            // elementB < elementA
            indexB++;
            if (indexB == sizeB)
                return true;
            elementB = sortedB.get(indexB);
        }
    }
}
```

Also consider using lists of primitive `int`s instead of boxed integers, e. g. from [fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) library.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can use a boolean array. Where the index of the array is the number and the value of the boolean returns `true` when it is a prim otherwise `false`.

Comment: This array holds decomposition of first 10M numbers. A 10M x 3K ~30 G array sounds like a stretch. realistically, I would need 10M x 10M if I don't want to compute the largest primes.

Comment: Okay that I have not known. Eventually you can use a `HashSet` for the primes?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
List<Integer> commonElements = 
       primeFactors.get(d).stream()
                          .filter(primeFactors.get(c)::contains)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Once you measure this performance, you can substitute 'parallelStream()' for 'stream()' above and see what benefits you derive.

Comment: `parallelStream()` is for *really* long streams or for *really* expensive tasks to compute on each element, not for list of factors and filtering them by `list::constains`